# sequelize beforeCreate hook or bycrypt hashing

Tags: express, sequelize.js

i have created a server using express and i have come across two interesting topics

- 1. sequelize `beforeCreate hook`
- 2. bycrypt.hash

when a user registers,i want his/her password to be hashed.Both solutions work perfectly but which one is the best to hash user password and why?

Answer (score 1):

The question probably shouldn't be which one is best, let me explain. For starters, to hash a password you have to use bcrypt hashing(assuming that's your selected hashing library), with or without a sequelize hook.

Sequelize beforeCreate hook is a block of code(function) you want to run before you create a row with sequelize. It's usually defined on the sequelize model level separate frm your business logic(controller). When using the before create hook with regards to password hashing, it means you'd call your hashing function/method in the model under the beforeCreate hook, to hash the plain password that was supposed to be saved to the DB.

Sequelize has other hooks, afterFind, afterUpdate, beforeDestroy, whose names describe when those functions would be run.

You can read more on it here: [sequelize hooks](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/hooks/)

Coming back to your question, it really depends on you. You could decide to hash your password either in your business logic(controllers) or in your model, with the beforeCreate hook. I hope this helps.